# I have student-subject-marks table and i want to achieve the result present in the second table. marks should not be the hard coded

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[This table is given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhPep.png)

[image: This table is given]

[I want to achieve the results as shown in result table, marks should not be hard coded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/augFJ.png)

[image: I want to achieve the results as shown in result table, marks should not be hard coded]

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2:C&E1:G1, {I2:I&J2:J, K2:K}, 2, )))
```

[image]